# Blank first line of shell script: explain behavior of UID variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have two very simple scripts, differing only by the presence of a blank first line:

```
$ cat test.bash
#!/bin/bash
echo ${UID}
$ cat test_blank.bash

#!/bin/bash
echo ${UID}
```

Now I run then, with and without `nice`:

```
$ ./test.bash
1060

$ ./test_blank.bash
1060

$ nice ./test.bash
1060

$ nice ./test_blank.bash
```

Please explain why, in the final case, the `UID` variable is unset. The behavior is the same when replacing `nice` with `sudo` or `nohup`.

Comment: If you also echo the value of `$SHELL` (and perhaps `$0`) in the script you might get a clue. Also read up on how the shebang `#!` line works.

Comment: I can't reproduce (not on OS X at least, but shebang handling is known to differ across OSes). Regarding @EtanReisner's suggestion: I don't think `$SHELL` helps much, because it's inherited from the environment and could be anything. As for `$0`, isn't it just the invoked script path? How does that give you a clue?

Comment: @4ae1e1 Hm... true `$SHELL` and `$0` aren't as helpful as I might have hoped they would be here. (Though un-exporting `$SHELL` should let it do what I wanted assuming most shells set it themselves when it is unset.)   Which, I guess, leaves John1024's answer as the best way to find out the information I was trying to hint at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe:

```
$ bash test_blank.bash
1060
$ dash test_blank.bash
```

`bash` produces output but `dash`, which is the default `sh` on debian-like systems, does not.  This is because `bash` sets `UID` but dash does not.  ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) does not require a shell to set `UID`.)  So, the question becomes which shell executes the script.

When bash sees `./test.sh`, it (bash) runs the script.  When another command, such as `nice`, receives the script as an argument and the script does not have a valid shebang as the first line, then the default shell, likely `dash`, is run.

If you want UID in dash, or any other shell that does not provide it, use the `id` command:

```
UID=$(id -u)
```

#### Finding out which shell is running a script

To see which shell is running a script, use:

```
$ cat test2.sh

#!/bin/bash
ps $$
echo UID=${UID}
```

Under `bash`:

```
$ ./test2.sh
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1652 pts/12   S+     0:00 bash -rcfile .bashrc
UID=1060
```

If we invoke it using `nice`, by contrast, we can see that it is running under `/bin/sh` and the UID variable is not assigned:

```
$ nice test2.sh
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 1659 pts/12   SN+    0:00 /bin/sh test2.sh
UID=
```